# Trial period end check timing of Adobe CS6 softwares

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I've been using the trial versions of Photoshop and Illustrator for at least 45-50 days now. Just wondering because, I never shut these processes down, thus they are still running (yes, computer has a long uptime). Can I assume that the end-of-trial check in CS6 softwares only occur on process launch?

Trial versions are 30 days now aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's true. Everytime you launch the application it checks for license.